# Journey builder based on Sendable DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, landing-page

I have created Sendable DE and I have created form on landing page. When user fill that form then data from that fields are inserted into my created DE using post method and AMp Script.

User will select care center and interested product in the form and we want to initialize journey builder and our goal will be : he should do registration for that product.

I have started to build journey. I have selected entry point is API and then select my DE and select contact filter as event data (Email not equal to null).

Should I create contact attribute and linked to DE? I want to send an automated email to the person who email is in DE after they submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have everything set up except for the API. Follow the documentation to get this going. This is required to inject the contacts into the journey realtime:

**Getting Started With Journey Builder API**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/get-started-jb.htm

**Getting API Key/Access Tokens**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-api-key.htm

Comment: Could you please explain it little bit more??

Comment: I have found this link : https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/step-by-step-guide-to-sending-an-email-with-journey-builder.md. we have email field on form. using the steps from above link,  would i be able to send email to that email id??

Comment: I had a quick read and those instructions aren't easy to follow. It also looks like they are instructions are on how to setup a journey based on a scheduled automation.

You're initial questions says that you want to set it up as an API trigger. This is not as straight forward as triggering a journey through an automation. You'll have to go through the links I have listed above to get it working.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'email id'. If you're using that as a primary key then you can link that up to ContactID in Contact Builder by creating an Attribute Group with your Journey DE.

Comment: Here's how to create attribute groups: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/getting_started_with_contact_builder/create_attribute_group/

Comment: Hamish Wilson Thanks for your reply! I am very new to SFMC and not very good with API.  I just want to explain the exact requirement. Capture the data in Marketing Cloud which will we get from landing page form submission  and assigned to Contact and If the contact already exists, the data will override the existing details.

Comment: our progress: we have successfully designed the form and we also able to store that values received in sendable Data extension with email ID as primary key(Email id is one field in the form submission). We are struggling how can we assign these values to contact.

Comment: Can we complete above requirement(Capture the data in Marketing Cloud which will we get from landing page form submission and assigned to Contact and If the contact already exists, the data will override the existing details) without journey builder?

Comment: If you're looking to just capture data and send one email then you don't need to trigger a journey at all. You can just use a custom landing page using AMPscript to save the data whilst checking whether or not a contact exists already etc, then use the API to do a triggered send.

Comment: A Triggered Send is an immediate email send which you can setup to be triggered from a landing page form submission. Here's a rundown: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/

Comment: thanks for your help!! just wanted to check if we relate data extension to contact by relating contact key with Email and if i insert row in data extension by using AMP script getting values from landing page then will it insert into contact?? Actually I am very confuse with contact and data extension

Comment: So usually you would avoid using email address as ContactID however I'm not sure how you're data is being setup. If you add a new record with the DE linked to All Contacts then the new record will be added.

Comment: It would be really great if you tell me how should i relate my DE to all contacts??

Comment: You have to do it through Contact Builder and create Attribute Groups. Link your primary key to Contact ID.